# Can I record Skype calls, but separate audio files?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, skype

Currently I'm using OSX but want to switch to Ubuntu. I record a podcast using Skype as my co host is in another country. We record using Ecamm call recorder.

Then with Ecamm movie tools (this is a companion app for the call recorder and can separate, and convert, the voices recorded in Skype into separate audio files, but is OSX only). This is great, because when I'm editing I can remove delays, or noises on my side without touching my co-hosts vocals.

I've done some forum searching and googling, but people don't seem to do the separation part. Are there tools similar to these in Ubuntu?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is tricky to answer without knowing your specific setup, but here's a possible solution that will eliminate having to separate the voices later.

*To record two audio devices simultaneously and separately*, you'll need software that can do multi track recording, such as [Ardour](https://ardour.org/).

Use [JACK](http://www.jackaudio.org/) to route the audio from Skype into ardour.

I'd recommend using a low latency kernel as well. All of these are part of the [Ubuntu Studio](https://ubuntustudio.org/) audio packages which can be installed on an existing Ubuntu system or as a new system.